# Can you write a powershell script that does the same thing as BGInfo?

Tags: powershell, scripting

I want to be able to display my computer name, internal and external IP, domain etc on my desktop. I was wondering if it would be possible to write a Powershell script to do this or if I actually will have to use BGInfo or something similar.

Comment: .NET contains types that allow image manipulation (eg. writing text) and WMI would allow getting the information. Therefore PSH could be used up update an image of suitable size and type with configuration information. But then you would need to select that image as the user's desktop. Just using BGInfo could be easier...

Comment: **Would** be easier, not could be easier.

Comment: @EBGreen If tringenb happened to work in an organization where using BGInfo required the user to thread a camel through the eye of a needle, then using BGInfo would not be easier than, say, a PS script. My point of course, is that we don't know what constraints tringenb has to work under.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to do this in PowerShell script as opposed to using BGInfo, here is a script that can get you started:

```
function Write-Bitmap
{
    param($imagePath, $newImagePath, [string[]]$Text, [float]$X = 0, [float]$Y = 0)

    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

    $bmp = $font = $g = $null

    try {
        $width = $rect.Right - $rect.Left + 1
        $height = $rect.Bottom - $rect.Top + 1
        $bmp = new-object System.Drawing.Bitmap $imagePath
        $g = [System.Drawing.Graphics]::FromImage($bmp)
        $font = new-object System.Drawing.Font 'Segoe UI',24
        $brush = [Drawing.Brushes]::Black
        foreach ($line in $text) {
            $g.DrawString($line, $font, $brush, $X, $Y)
            $Y += 30
        }
        $bmp.Save($newImagePath)
    }
    finally {
        if ($bmp) { $bmp.Dispose() }
        if ($font) { $font.Dispose() }
        if ($g) { $g.Dispose() }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this as a starting point:
https://p0w3rsh3ll.wordpress.com/2014/08/29/poc-tatoo-the-background-of-your-virtual-machines/

Here is the script I ended up with:
https://gist.github.com/dieseltravis/3066def0ddaf7a8a0b6d

```
# PS-BGInfo
# Powershell script that updates the background image with a random image from a folder and writes out system info text to it.

# Configuration:

# Font Family name
$font="Input"
# Font size in pixels
$size=10.0
# spacing in pixels
$textPaddingLeft = 5
$textPaddingTop = 5
$textItemSpace = 3
#TODO: Line-height multiplyer of the $size in pixels.
#$lineHeight = 1.80

$wallpaperImagesSource = "$Env:USERPROFILE\Pictures\wallpaper"
$wallpaperImageOutput = "$Env:USERPROFILE"

# Get local info to write out to wallpaper
$os = Get-CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem
$cpu = (Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor).Name.Replace("Intel(R) Core(TM) ", "")
$BootTimeSpan = (New-TimeSpan -Start $os.LastBootUpTime -End (Get-Date))
$ip = (Get-NetIPAddress | Where-Object {$_.InterfaceAlias -eq "Ethernet" -and  $_.AddressFamily -eq "IPv4"}).IPAddress

$o = ([ordered]@{
    User = $os.RegisteredUser
    Host = "$($os.CSName) `n$($os.Description)"
    CPU = $cpu
    RAM = "$([math]::round($os.TotalVisibleMemorySize / 1MB))GB"
    OS = "$($os.Caption) `n$($os.OSArchitecture), $($os.Version)"
    Boot = $os.LastBootUpTime
    Uptime = "$($BootTimeSpan.Days) days, $($BootTimeSpan.Hours) hours"
    Snapshot = $os.LocalDateTime
    IP = $ip
})

# original src: https://p0w3rsh3ll.wordpress.com/2014/08/29/poc-tatoo-the-background-of-your-virtual-machines/
Function New-ImageInfo {
    # src: https://github.com/fabriceleal/Imagify/blob/master/imagify.ps1
    param(  
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, Position=1)]
        [object] $data,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [string] $in="",
        [string] $font="Courier New",
        [float] $size=12.0,
        #[float] $lineHeight = 1.4,
        [float] $textPaddingLeft = 0,
        [float] $textPaddingTop = 0,
        [float] $textItemSpace = 0,
        [string] $out="out.png" 
    )


    [system.reflection.assembly]::loadWithPartialName('system') | out-null
    [system.reflection.assembly]::loadWithPartialName('system.drawing') | out-null
    [system.reflection.assembly]::loadWithPartialName('system.drawing.imaging') | out-null
    [system.reflection.assembly]::loadWithPartialName('system.windows.forms') | out-null

    $foreBrush  = [System.Drawing.Brushes]::White
    $backBrush  = new-object System.Drawing.SolidBrush([System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(192, 0, 0, 0))

    # Create font
    $nFont = new-object system.drawing.font($font, $size, [System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit]::Pixel)

    # Create Bitmap
    $SR = [System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::AllScreens | Where Primary | Select -ExpandProperty Bounds | Select Width,Height

    echo $SR >> "$wallpaperImageOutput\wallpaper.log"

    $background = new-object system.drawing.bitmap($SR.Width, $SR.Height)
    $bmp = new-object system.drawing.bitmap -ArgumentList $in

    # Create Graphics
    $image = [System.Drawing.Graphics]::FromImage($background)

    # Paint image's background
    $rect = new-object system.drawing.rectanglef(0, 0, $SR.width, $SR.height)
    $image.FillRectangle($backBrush, $rect)

    # add in image
    $topLeft = new-object System.Drawing.RectangleF(0, 0, $SR.Width, $SR.Height)
    $image.DrawImage($bmp, $topLeft)

    # Draw string
    $strFrmt = new-object system.drawing.stringformat
    $strFrmt.Alignment = [system.drawing.StringAlignment]::Near
    $strFrmt.LineAlignment = [system.drawing.StringAlignment]::Near

    $taskbar = [System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::AllScreens
    $taskbarOffset = $taskbar.Bounds.Height - $taskbar.WorkingArea.Height

    # first get max key & val widths
    $maxKeyWidth = 0
    $maxValWidth = 0
    $textBgHeight = 0 + $taskbarOffset
    $textBgWidth = 0

    # a reversed ordered collection is used since it starts from the bottom
    $reversed = [ordered]@{}

    foreach ($h in $data.GetEnumerator()) {
        $valString = "$($h.Value)"
        $valFont = New-Object System.Drawing.Font($font, $size, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Regular)
        $valSize = [system.windows.forms.textrenderer]::MeasureText($valString, $valFont)
        $maxValWidth = [math]::Max($maxValWidth, $valSize.Width)

        $keyString = "$($h.Name): "
        $keyFont = New-Object System.Drawing.Font($font, $size, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
        $keySize = [system.windows.forms.textrenderer]::MeasureText($keyString, $keyFont)
        $maxKeyWidth = [math]::Max($maxKeyWidth, $keySize.Width)

        $maxItemHeight = [math]::Max($valSize.Height, $keySize.Height)
        $textBgHeight += ($maxItemHeight + $textItemSpace)

        $reversed.Insert(0, $h.Name, $h.Value)
    }

    $textBgWidth = $maxKeyWidth + $maxValWidth
    $textBgX = $SR.Width - ($textBgWidth + $textPaddingLeft)
    $textBgY = $SR.Height - ($textBgHeight + $textPaddingTop)

    $textBgRect = New-Object System.Drawing.RectangleF($textBgX, $textBgY, $textBgWidth, $textBgHeight)
    $image.FillRectangle($backBrush, $textBgRect)

    echo $textBgRect >> "$wallpaperImageOutput\wallpaper.log"

    $i = 0
    $cumulativeHeight = $SR.Height - $taskbarOffset

    foreach ($h in $reversed.GetEnumerator()) {
        $valString = "$($h.Value)"
        $valFont = New-Object System.Drawing.Font($font, $size, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Regular)
        $valSize = [system.windows.forms.textrenderer]::MeasureText($valString, $valFont)

        $keyString = "$($h.Name): "
        $keyFont = New-Object System.Drawing.Font($font, $size, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
        $keySize = [system.windows.forms.textrenderer]::MeasureText($keyString, $keyFont)

        echo $valString >> "$wallpaperImageOutput\wallpaper.log"
        echo $keyString >> "$wallpaperImageOutput\wallpaper.log"

        $maxItemHeight = [math]::Max($valSize.Height, $keySize.Height) + $textItemSpace

        $valX = $SR.Width - $maxValWidth
        $valY = $cumulativeHeight - $maxItemHeight

        $keyX = $valX - $maxKeyWidth
        $keyY = $valY

        $valRect = New-Object System.Drawing.RectangleF($valX, $valY, $maxValWidth, $valSize.Height)
        $keyRect = New-Object System.Drawing.RectangleF($keyX, $keyY, $maxKeyWidth, $keySize.Height)

        $cumulativeHeight = $valRect.Top

        $image.DrawString($keyString, $keyFont, $foreBrush, $keyRect, $strFrmt)
        $image.DrawString($valString, $valFont, $foreBrush, $valRect, $strFrmt)

        $i++
    }

    # Close Graphics
    $image.Dispose();

    # Save and close Bitmap
    $background.Save($out, [system.drawing.imaging.imageformat]::Png);
    $background.Dispose();
    $bmp.Dispose();

    # Output file
    Get-Item -Path $out
}

Function Set-Wallpaper {
    # src: http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tips/archive/2014/01/10/change-desktop-wallpaper.aspx
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        $Path,

        [ValidateSet('Center', 'Stretch', 'Fill', 'Tile', 'Fit')]
        $Style = 'Center'
    )

    #TODO: there in't a better way to do this than inline C#?
    Add-Type @"
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace Wallpaper
{
    public enum Style : int
    {
        Center, Stretch, Fill, Fit, Tile
    }

    public class Setter {
        public const int SetDesktopWallpaper = 20;
        public const int UpdateIniFile = 0x01;
        public const int SendWinIniChange = 0x02;

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern int SystemParametersInfo (int uAction, int uParam, string lpvParam, int fuWinIni);

        public static void SetWallpaper ( string path, Wallpaper.Style style ) 
        {
            SystemParametersInfo( SetDesktopWallpaper, 0, path, UpdateIniFile | SendWinIniChange );
            RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Control Panel\\Desktop", true);
            switch( style )
            {
                case Style.Tile :
                    key.SetValue(@"WallpaperStyle", "0") ; 
                    key.SetValue(@"TileWallpaper", "1") ; 
                    break;
                case Style.Center :
                    key.SetValue(@"WallpaperStyle", "0") ; 
                    key.SetValue(@"TileWallpaper", "0") ; 
                    break;
                case Style.Stretch :
                    key.SetValue(@"WallpaperStyle", "2") ; 
                    key.SetValue(@"TileWallpaper", "0") ;
                    break;
                case Style.Fill :
                    key.SetValue(@"WallpaperStyle", "10") ; 
                    key.SetValue(@"TileWallpaper", "0") ; 
                    break;
                case Style.Fit :
                    key.SetValue(@"WallpaperStyle", "6") ; 
                    key.SetValue(@"TileWallpaper", "0") ; 
                    break;
            }
            key.Close();
        }
    }
}
"@

    [Wallpaper.Setter]::SetWallpaper( $Path, $Style )
}

# execute tasks

echo $o > "$wallpaperImageOutput\wallpaper.log"

# get random wallpaper from a folder full of images
Get-ChildItem -Path "$wallpaperImagesSource\*" -Include *.* -Exclude current.jpg | Get-Random | Foreach-Object { Copy-Item -Path $_ -Destination "$wallpaperImagesSource\current.jpg" }

# create wallpaper image and save it in user profile
$WallPaper = New-ImageInfo -data $o -in "$wallpaperImagesSource\current.jpg" -out "$wallpaperImageOutput\wallpaper.png" -font $font -size $size -textPaddingLeft $textPaddingLeft -textPaddingTop $textPaddingTop -textItemSpace $textItemSpace #-lineHeight $lineHeight
echo $WallPaper.FullName >> "$wallpaperImageOutput\wallpaper.log"

# update wallpaper for logged in user
Set-Wallpaper -Path $WallPaper.FullName
```

It writes out this info on the lower-right corner of the wallpaper:

[image: info]

I didn't bother with any other positioning than lower-right, but feel free to fork and solve that if you'd like. I have a scheduled task that updates it every few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I am late on the question, but me too, I would like to share with you my script for this purpose (2011) and I decided to publish it to Technet recently https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/LockScreenInfo-Display-2adfc20b
Best regards.

```
PS> .\LockScreenInfo.ps1 -SourceImage C:\temp\abstract.jpg -FitScreen -KeepRatio -MessagePicture "C:\Users\install\Pictures\advancedsettings.png" -MessageText "Welcome to StackOverflow!" -TargetImage C:\Temp\Background.jpg
```

[Sample tatoued background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4K4s.jpg)